# How to deploy an Internal HTTP(S) LoadBalancer using Google Deployment Manager (Python + YAML)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager, infrastructure-as-code, gcp-load-balancer

I'm implementing IaC for a web application consisting of monoliths and microservices. I want to place an [internal HTTP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal) in front of all our microservices and have not found any example for that yet. I looked at [Cloud Foundation Toolkit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit). The Internal Load Balancer here supports only TCP / UDP Internal LoadBalancer. Google's [deploymentmanager-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples) has no mention of it at all!! At this moment, it seems like the only option is to build the python template from scratch.

Before I jump into that rabbit hole, wanted check if any working sample or example is available on this.

Answer (score 5):

According to some Google document, You just need to modify some values in the internal TCP LB template.

Below is regionBackendService of internal TCP LB sample code.

```
{
      'name': loadbalancer_name,
      'type': 'compute.v1.regionBackendService',
      'properties': {
          'region': properties['region'],
          'network': properties['network'],
          'healthChecks': ['$(ref.' + healthcheck_name + '.selfLink)'],
          'backends': properties['instance-groups'],
          'protocol': 'TCP',
          'loadBalancingScheme': 'INTERNAL',
      }
  }
```

And this is `compute.v1.regionBackendService` reference at [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionBackendServices).

> protocol
>
> Possible values are HTTP, HTTPS, HTTP2, TCP, SSL, UDP or GRPC.
> depending on the chosen load balancer or Traffic Director
> configuration. Refer to the documentation for the load balancer or for
> Traffic Director for more information.

> loadBalancingScheme
>
> Choose INTERNAL_MANAGED for Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing.

So you need to modify `'protocol':'TCP'` to `'protocol':'HTTP'` or `HTTPS`, and `'loadBalancingScheme': 'INTERNAL'` to `'loadBalancingScheme': 'INTERNAL_MANAGED'`.

Below is forwardingRule of TCP intenal LB code.

```
{
      'name': forwardingrule_name,
      'type': 'compute.v1.forwardingRule',
      'properties': {
          'ports': [80],
          'network': properties['network'],
          'subnetwork': properties['subnet'],
          'region': properties['region'],
          'backendService': '$(ref.' + loadbalancer_name + '.selfLink)',
          'loadBalancingScheme': 'INTERNAL',
      }
  }
```

And you can find [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/forwardingRules) about this resource too.

> loadBalancingScheme
>
> INTERNAL_MANAGED is used for:
> Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing

> IPProtocol
>
> Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing: The load balancing scheme is
> INTERNAL_MANAGED, and only TCP is valid.

As a result, You need to modify `loadBalancingScheme` value from `INTERNAL` to `INTERNAL_MANAGED`.
Or you maybe need to add the IPProtocol value to your forwardingrule.

Lastly, below is healthcheck of TCP internal LB code.

```
{
      'name': healthcheck_name,
      'type': 'compute.v1.healthCheck',
      'properties': {
          'type': 'TCP',
          'tcpHealthCheck': {
              'port': 80
          },
      }
  }
```

As i found in [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/healthChecks#resource:-healthcheck), You must use a '[regionhealthcheck](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regionHealthChecks)' instead 'healthcheck' for http(s) internal LB .

So you need to modify resource type to `compute.v1.regionHealthChecks`

I'm not completely sure for my description, but you can create your own HTTP(S) internal LB enough through referring to the Google documentation and sample code.

Comment: Please click check botton to accept my answer if it was helpful enough :)

Comment: I'll test this first :)

Comment: hey, also check this documentation, may be of your interest :)
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/monitoring

Comment: Forgot to update here, but I made it work. In reality, it is closer to External HTTP LB than an Internal TCP LB. I had to use all regional resources instead of the non-regional ones. 2 extra requirements are: the regionalTargetHTTPProxy requires a proxy only subnet and a firewall rule to allow traffic from the proxy only subnet to the internal network where the MIGs are running.

Comment: Right now it is a config only deployment. I'm planning to convert it into a template and add it back to cloudfoundry.

Comment: I currently have some issue with update for ILB, will probably spawn a separate question for that...